# Error while including atltime header into WTL project

Tags: c++, atl, wtl

After I created a plain dialog using the Dialog wizard in WTL - Visual studio 9 I have included the `<atltime.h>` header and I get this:

```
Error   2   error C2039: 'CString' : is not a member of 'WTL'   ...\wtl\include\atlctrls.h  5060    TASKSCHEDULER
Error   3   error C2039: 'CString' : is not a member of 'WTL'   ...\wtl\include\atlctrls.h  969 TASKSCHEDULER
Error   4   error C2039: 'CString' : is not a member of 'WTL'   ...\wtl\include\atldlgs.h   535 TASKSCHEDULER
Error   5   error C2039: 'CString' : is not a member of 'WTL'   ...\wtl\include\atldlgs.h   627 TASKSCHEDULER
Error   6   error C2039: 'CString' : is not a member of 'WTL'   ...\wtl\include\atldlgs.h

697 TASKSCHEDULER
```

Comment: Make sure your #include is not inside a namespace

Comment: Have you tried including <afx.h>?

Comment: I have solved this problem in the simple dialog creation using the wizard by including atlstr.h before atlapp.h and after atlbase.h. But in a bigger project, the problems pops everywhere saying that  'CString' : ambiguous symbol.

Comment: I do typedef WTL::CString CString or typedef ATL::CAtlString CString, but it still pops the same error.

Comment: I have changed them all by hand, from CString to CAtlString

Comment: `CString` is available in both `ATL` and `WTL` namespaces (different implementations). You need to use `using namespace ...` or similar to resolve the confusion.

Comment: It is not to mentioned that your Q is imcomplete in first place. Adding `#include <atltime.h>` (below `#include <atlbase.h>` in particular) on the fresh created project does not lead to any errors.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar situation and there were two things helped me get rid of the error, maybe of help to someone else.

1. include `atlstr.h` above `atlapp.h`
2. define `_WTL_NO_CSTRING`

Comment: Look in the readme.html of the latest WTL release for a fuller answer to this problem